# How to fix "This repository can be attached only to ORM sortable listener" error in Gedmo sortable?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jquery-ui-sortable, doctrine-extensions

When usieing StofDoctrineExtensions (which is a Symfony2 port of Gedmo Doctrine Extensions) Sortable behaviour I kept on getting this error:

> This repository can be attached only to ORM sortable listener

Since I could not easily find the answer in official docs I'm leaving an answer here for future reference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to enable any listeners you are using. In this case, Sortable.

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            sortable: true
```

For Symfony 4, add this configuration in `/config/packages/stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml`. For older versions of Symfony, add it to `config.yml`.

Comment: does this enable sortable in all bundles (so that code in boot method from my answer is no longer neccesary?)

Comment: Yes it does. You would use the code in your boot method if you were using the Sortable extension without the Stof bundle. The stof bundle does the code for you.

Comment: Still the way to go for Symfony 4, except this has to be put in /config/packages/stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Sortable behaviour you need to add an event listener to your bundle's boot method

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeDemoBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // get the doctrine 2 entity manager
        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');

        // get the event manager
        $evm = $em->getEventManager();
        $evm->addEventSubscriber(new \Gedmo\Sortable\SortableListener);
    }
}
```