# Error at login: This repository can be attached only to ORM sortable listener

Tags: php, symfony

I am currently verifying the operation by upgrading to Symfony 4.0.   When I tried to log in by entering my ID and password, the following error message appeared.
Is there anything you can think of?
StofDoctrine Extensions wasn't used until Symfony 3.4.

**Error message**

```
This repository can be attached only to ORM sortable listener
```

**Code**

BaseRepository.php

```php
use Gedmo\Sortable\Entity\Repository\SortableRepository;

/**
 * Repository base class
 */
class BaseRepository extends SortableRepository
{

    /**
      * Get an expression that converts gender to a sortable value
      *
      * Add the obtained expression to the SELECT clause and specify the alias specified in $ alias in the ORDER BY clause.
     *
     * @param $sex sex
     * @param $alias Another name for the converted value
     */
    public function toSortableSex($sex, $alias)
    {
        return "case {$sex} when 0 then 1 when 1 then 0 else {$sex} end as hidden {$alias}";
    }
}
```

config/package/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

var/log/dev.log

```
[2021-01-25 10:43:31] request.INFO: Matched route "app_security_login". {"route":"app_security_login","route_parameters":{"_controller":"App\\Controller\\SecurityController::loginAction","_route":"app_security_login"},"request_uri":"http://192.168.33.70/admin/login","method":"GET"} []
[2021-01-25 10:43:31] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2021-01-25 10:43:31] php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route" annotation is deprecated since version 5.2. Use "Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route" instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: The \"Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle\\Configuration\\Route\" annotation is deprecated since version 5.2. Use \"Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Annotation\\Route\" instead. at /home/vagrant/Symfony2/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Configuration/Route.php:16)"} []
[2021-01-25 10:43:31] translation.WARNING: Translation not found. {"id":"This repository can be attached only to ORM sortable listener","domain":"messages","locale":"en"} []
[2021-01-25 10:43:31] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Creating Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UnderscoreNamingStrategy without making it number aware is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine ORM 3.0. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Creating Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\UnderscoreNamingStrategy without making it number aware is deprecated and will be removed in Doctrine ORM 3.0. at /home/vagrant/Symfony2/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/UnderscoreNamingStrategy.php:66)"} []
[2021-01-25 10:43:31] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"178c6f","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://192.168.33.70/_wdt/178c6f","method":"GET"} []
```

**Version**
Symfony 4.0.15
PHP7.4
gedmo/doctrine-extensions 2.3.12

Comment: Could you add "the following error message appeared"?

Comment: @qdequippe Thanks for your comment. Please check the added message.

Comment: You accidentally edited the title to be non-English. I've fixed it now, but please be careful about that in the future.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414243/how-to-fix-this-repository-can-be-attached-only-to-orm-sortable-listener-error) might answer your question.

Comment: @cigien Thank you for the fix. I'll be careful next time.

Comment: @Joundill Thank you for your suggestion. However, I don't use StofDoctrine Extensions.

Comment: It's a warning I see not an error and it's about "Translation" there is a component for this in StofDoctrineExtension to translate data in database. This message appears as an error on your app? Try do deactivate this component in stofDoctrine config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't moving doctrine_extensions.yaml from app/config/ to config/packages/. I apologize for the inconvenience.

doctrine_extensions.yaml

```yaml
# services to handle doctrine extensions
# import it in config.yml
services:
    # Doctrine Extension listeners to handle behaviors
    gedmo.listener.softdeleteable:
        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader" ] ]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }

    gedmo.listener.sortable:
        class: Gedmo\Sortable\SortableListener
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader" ] ]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```